# Rails Devise "Invalid Email or password" when password is correct and Email is not a parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using the `Devise` gem to perform basic authentication. In `application_controller.rb`, I have the following as a `before_action`:

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:name, :password])
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_in, keys: [:name, :password])
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:name, :password])
end
```

When I try to log in using a simple name/password form, I get the error: "Invalid Email or password." I know the name and password are correct. Email isn't even a parameter being sent:

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-03-12 02:47:06 -0700
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ltvCys0g2WE8JWRaoQOYbt6LLe9mtJGCQ0hAoCiLCVsXAvfLuTpm02jrJnLjKk4AARSO1B9YLe3QyTTBs1d8iw==", "user"=>{"name"=>"my_name", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Here is `user.rb`:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :rememberable, :trackable, :lockable,
         :database_authenticatable, :timeoutable,
         :recoverable

  validates :name,
            :presence => true,
            :uniqueness => {
              :case_sensitive => false
            }

  def self.find_for_database_authentication(warden_conditions)
    conditions = warden_conditions.dup
    if login = conditions.delete(:login)
      where(conditions.to_hash)
        .where(["name = :value OR email = :value",
                { :value => login.downcase }]).first
    elsif conditions.has_key?(:name) || conditions.has_key?(:email)
      where(conditions.to_h).first
    end
  end

  def password_required?
    true
  end

end
```

And here is the user, as the console sees it (slightly redacted):

```
pry(main)> ap me
#<User:0x000056172bdd0e80> {
                        :id => 1,
                      :name => "my_name",
                     :email => "my_name@example.com",
                     :phone => "520 555 1212",
                  :initials => "amp",
                      :role => "admin",
                    :active => true,
                :created_at => Fri, 08 Mar 2019 00:12:33 UTC +00:00,
                :updated_at => Mon, 11 Mar 2019 17:17:11 UTC +00:00,
           :current_prop_id => 1,
        :encrypted_password => "$2a$11$2s/n.eaBCF731fTor3hW2OsD9kLXQkJnjKLoFN/27vYku/1GbvzW2",
      :reset_password_token => nil,
    :reset_password_sent_at => nil,
       :remember_created_at => nil
}
```

Why am I failing to login?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Devise by default uses email for sign in. I see that you have used name for sign up and sign in. In order to use anyother parameter for Sign in, the configuration needs to be modified.

in config/initializers/devise.rb file set
config.authentication_keys = [:username]

please refer the following for more details:
[signing in with something other than email](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-with-something-other-than-their-email-address)